# Python, lists, arrays, tuples, data - How to deal with a particular dataset

Tags: python, arrays, list, file-io, tuples

I hope this time I give you enough info to explain myself.
I am trying to read in velocity data, in vector notation, in order to (for now) plot some XY scatter plots.
The files look like:

```
#               x            0.0025             0.005            0.0075              0.01             0.015              0.02              0.03              0.04              0.05              0.06              0.08               0.1              0.12              0.14              0.16              0.18               0.2
#               y                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0
#               z                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0                 0
#            Time
           50                 (0.0007558915435 -0.0004561530839 -0.0004827045695)                 (0.002621093455 -0.0004982563588 -0.0004670886403)                 (0.004284814163 -0.0004701779131 -0.0003427572777)                 (0.005427856321 -0.0004415657508 -0.0002581055849)                 (0.009283872431 -0.0003824524669 -9.862169137e-05)                 (0.01336058599 -0.0003623751773 -3.007799017e-05)                 (0.02241437059 -0.0002222313074 0.0001136439177)                 (0.03056537385 -4.38083924e-05 0.0002682758253)                 (0.038580681 -4.613463513e-06 0.0002734791838)                 (0.04315368113 7.912822938e-05 0.0002553115381)                 (0.04920978201 0.0001259194082 0.0001679574544)                 (0.05178246176 3.113282703e-05 8.74525373e-05)                 (0.05351566041 -6.546046173e-07 5.251841968e-05)                 (0.05470950178 5.582683289e-06 5.456222367e-05)                 (0.05765609801 1.604055123e-05 5.61024635e-05)                 (0.05910960178 8.390667426e-06 5.051911761e-05)                 (0.06047027361 -3.362615186e-06 5.137448521e-05)
          100                 (-0.03638183522 -0.0004212943087 -0.0001445116086)                 (-0.04599742972 1.934674765e-05 0.0002080845418)                 (-0.0263580529 0.0007034850972 0.0007206210834)                 (-0.005878665916 0.0009878563826 0.0009139785036)                 (0.03751451082 0.0008459502289 0.0008117077564)                 (0.06155058308 0.0007058376794 0.0007077796084)                 (0.09253546972 0.0005743407599 0.0005878527131)                 (0.1056482525 0.0004776711045 0.0005015883363)                 (0.1147274675 0.0003535542095 0.0003873958082)                 (0.1197626602 0.0003578742091 0.0003643755411)                 (0.1264856441 0.0003138045371 0.0003051010097)                 (0.1307027216 0.0002453538171 0.0002362933067)                 (0.1347570923 0.000177587389 0.0001672847755)                 (0.1366348914 0.0001554091899 0.000144292499)                 (0.1398319486 0.0001272587836 0.000111811677)                 (0.141127784 0.0001160117874 9.894530615e-05)                 (0.1422487007 0.0001054244658 8.819660841e-05)
          150                 (-0.05825943888 0.0001136539473 0.0004206885026)                 (-0.04572555779 0.0007272639883 0.0005475238907)                 (0.001189305157 0.001076000002 0.0006294173999)                 (0.02934769975 0.0009229883365 0.0006037649856)                 (0.07194848666 0.0006515992717 0.0005186304839)                 (0.09490965777 0.0005256600022 0.0004767879994)                 (0.1233413075 0.0004350708279 0.0004479392071)                 (0.1347607461 0.0003609992666 0.0003952444021)                 (0.1426707096 0.0002771968784 0.0003190311903)                 (0.147209712 0.0002727655531 0.0003053133615)                 (0.1532548565 0.0002247845037 0.0002564816634)                 (0.1570851548 0.0001718066583 0.0002036570558)                 (0.1608564722 0.0001242749078 0.0001549789597)                 (0.1626047646 0.0001093818898 0.0001393982173)                 (0.1656239159 9.055609841e-05 0.0001172163492)                 (0.1668961273 8.334132321e-05 0.0001085831113)                 (0.168037179 7.648813655e-05 0.0001009290741)
... and so on down to ...
        10000
```

The '...' mean there is more data, but I've had to cut "a little bit" to make it understandable. The data is separated by blank spaces.
I would like to understand which is the better way to deal with this kind of data in order to read it in, and plot it or write it in some other format, keeping or not the parentheses.

I was thinking in reading it in as list, getting rid of the '()' symbols, and plotting the data by slicing the list. Or, should I use an array?

In both scenarios, should I treat the vectors as tuples? or as lists? (inside the list or the array) or each number as a member of a list, in which case, I will have to be careful when plotting the X, Y or Z coordinates.

I have written some code already, but I am stuck. I just slept two hours last night and I'm paying the consequences right now :-(

The code:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#=============================================================================#
# The header of Velocity (U) probes shows the XYZ coordinates in separate     #
# lines. To work with the center line along the wake, we may assume Y=Z=0.    #
# Thus, we are interested in the values of X, in the first line of the file.  #
# The first character of each header line is '#', and the second character is #
# the coordinate, 'x' for the first line.                                     #
# The first element of interest will be [2] of the list                       #
#=============================================================================#

inFile = glob.glob("*.inp")  # list of files in current directory for input.

for Ufile in inFile:
    print("File Opened: ", Ufile)
    fi = open(Ufile, "rb")       # openning input file for reading.

    fileroot = Ufile[0:-4]       # keeping input file root for output file
    outfile = fileroot + '.out'  # adding extension
    fo = open(outfile, "wb")     # openning output file for writing

    try:
        inHead = fi.readlines()[0]  # Read X-coordinates and transform to float
        inHead = inHead.split()
        outHead = inHead[2:]

        inData = fi.readlines()[4:]    # Read data as strings. Skipping header
        r = 0
        for line in inData:
            fila = line.split()        # Divinding each row in elements
            c = 0
            for elem in fila:
                if elem[0] == '(':     # Slicing undesired character
                    elem = elem[1:]
                    fila[c] = float(elem)  # Converting string to float
                elif elem[-1] == ')':      # Slicing undesired character
                    elem = elem[0:-1]
                    fila[c] = float(elem)  # Converting string to float
                else:
                    fila[c] = float(elem)  # Converting string to float
                c += 1        # Tracking with row element the loop is at
            inData[r] = fila  # Updating list row with '(' and ')' removed
            r += 1


    finally:
        print("File Closed: ", Ufile)
        fi.close()
        fo.close()
```

Some of the indentation might be shown wrong when pasting the code here. What I show does what it is supposed to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `re.findall` to search for tuples. I believe all program would be 5-lines long or so

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use `open(Ufile, "r")` not `open(Ufile, "rb")` (also `wb`) because you are using text file.
Secondly, `inData = fi.readlines()[4:]` don't read anything (file pointer to the file end because you use `inHead = fi.readlines()[0]` before. You can use `fi.seek(0)` to reset it. Better, you can read all the lines to a var and use it for inHead and inData.
Third, you don't output anything...
You can use `elem.rstrip('\)').lstrip('\(')` instead of some codes..

Comment: Thank you platinhom,
Still dealing with this issue, but getting somewhere. Hope to post the solution soon!

Answer (score 0):

Using a list of lists(vectors) for each line could be a solution for you. But if each line has a set number of vector then inputing them into a numpy array would be the way forward.

However to process the string data the following should help:

```
import numpy as np

#The following assumes the data is read as lines of text in the following format
txt=["           50                 (0.0007558915435 -0.0004561530839 -0.0004827045695) .... (0.06047027361 -3.362615186e-06 5.137448521e-05)",
     "          100                 (-0.03638183522 -0.0004212943087 -0.0001445116086) .... (0.1422487007 0.0001054244658 8.819660841e-05)",
     "          150                 (-0.05825943888 0.0001136539473 0.0004206885026) ....  (0.168037179 7.648813655e-05 0.0001009290741)"]
complete_list = []

for line in txt:
    line_part = line.split('(')
    header = int(line_part[0].strip(' '))  #changed from .rstrip(' ')
    vector_list = []
    for vector in line_part[1:]:
        coords = vector.split(' ')
        X = float(coords[0])
        Y = float(coords[1])
        Z = float(coords[2].rstrip(')'))
        vector_list.append([X,Y,Z])
    vector_array = np.array(vector_list)
    complete_list.append([header,vector_array])

#addressing can be done as follows:
line = 1
vector =2
print("header\n",complete_list[line][0])
print("vector\n",complete_list[line][1][vector])
```

Comment: Thank you Colin, still working on it. I have changed the way to read the files. First of all, I am "dumping" them in a list, and will be dealing with the lines splitting, slicing, and having fun :-)

Comment: Sorry to ask again Colin, but I'm stuck.
Your suggestion is the one that approaches the closest to my problem, but still cannot figure out how to solve this.
So, as I said when I posted my problem, I have many lines from where I need to read numerical data, and I want to do that into an array. I can change your last line in the for-loop to "np.array(vector_list.append([U,V,W]))"
But, I get an error message: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' , at line "header = int(... "

Comment: @CarlosE.MV , okay sounds like the error is further up.  Could you post the first two lines of your data in full please.  It appears to be a simple problem interpreting the data.

Comment: I have edited my original post to add the data you ask for. To many characters to use this comment box. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosE.MV sorry for taking so long over this.  I've edited my answer, as i hadn't taken into account the spaces before the 'header' number.  Hopefully this should eliminate the error you got latterly. I've also added another loop to process all the lines of data, and given an example of how to read the results.  Hopefully this will now work!